# Removing indentation for solo "{" in emacs

Tags: c, emacs

While writing C programs in emacs (in C mode), I noticed that emacs indents lines with a single "{" as well. So, the code looks like this:

```
if (condition)
  {
    expression;
  }
else (condition)
  {
    expression;
  }
```

This is creating a lot of whitespace I don't want. What should I do so that "{" is not indented (the more conventional style)?

```
if (condition)
{
  expression;
}
else (condition)
{
  expression;
}
```

I went through all commands found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html), but couldn't find anything related to my problem.
The only line in my init file related to indentation is: `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`

(Side note: I found a similar command in Xcode preferences, under "Indent solo "{" by _ spaces", so I'm looking for something like that)

Comment: I guess `(setq-default c-basic-offset 0)` will do the trick.

Comment: @Zilog80 I'm afraid not. I tried that, but it stopped indenting altogether (so even `expression`) wasn't indented.

Comment: Found : Try `(setq c-brace-offset 0)` with M-x `eval-expression`.

Comment: @Zilog80 That didn't work for me either (don't know why). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798489/how-to-alter-emacs-c-indenting-style-to-not-indent-opening-brace-with-inline-c) answer worked though. Thanks.